# Asp.net, Jcrop value issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, jcrop

I trying to get Jcrop work with Asp.net but I think I have a issue with:

```cpp
Convert.ToInt32(W.Value);
```

I use Hidden fields in my aspx page. I tried to use regular input fields and then wrote a request form to get all the values, and that worked. But I cant get it to work with hidden fields and Convert.ToInt32(W.Value). It seems that the value always is null when I try that way. And I get the message: The input was not in a correct format.

My behind code looks like this:

```cpp
protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ImageName = Request.QueryString["upload"];
    String path = "~/Members/TemporaryProfilePhotos/";

    int w = Convert.ToInt32(W.Value);
    int h = Convert.ToInt32(H.Value);
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(X.Value);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(Y.Value);

    byte[] CropImage = Crop(path + ImageName, w, h, x, y);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length);
        using (SD.Image CroppedImage = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, true))
        {
            string SaveTo = path + "crop" + ImageName;
            CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);
        }
    }
}

static byte[] Crop(string Img, int Width, int Height, int X, int Y)
{
  try {
    using (SD.Image OriginalImage = SD.Image.FromFile(Img)) {
      using (SD.Bitmap bmp = new SD.Bitmap(Width, Height)) {
        bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution,
          OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);

        using (SD.Graphics Graphic = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
          Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
          Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
          Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
          Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage,
            new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height),
            X, Y, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
          bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);
          return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  catch (Exception Ex) {
    throw (Ex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Visible property` to `false;` typically in `.net` the `control` will not be rendered in the `HTML` output after the page is `processed`

So you can try with the hidden fields with `style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"`